# Cannot place custom items on client hotbar/toolbar

Tags: azerothcore

Whenever I make a custom item, I am unable to drag it onto a hotbar. When I try to pick it up the icon turns to a question mark and will not stick to a hotkey.

For example, I made an exact copy of the Murloc Costume (id 33079) at id 50017 (which was a free slot on my DB). The original I can put on a hotbar. The custom one I cannot.

[Here's a gif of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWK1x.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: if it's not in the client side DBC's, it will not work properly.

From ReynoldsCahoon on the AC Discord:

I just modified a DBC recently. I had to use a tool (I used Ladik's MPQ Editor) to extract the specific DBC I wanted to modify, and then I used WDBX to open the DBC and manipulate it. In WDBX you can output it in a variety of formats (like CSV or SQL) so you can modify the values any way you like, and then reimport (via CSV or SQL) the values back in.

I loosely followed the guide here: https://model-changing.net/tutorials/article/23-41-creating-your-first-mpq-patch/

I exported a DBC containing all of the Character Titles in the game. Erased all of them, and then imported a bunch of new values of my own choosing. Instead of importing that back into the MPQ I got it from, I created a new MPQ called patch-4.mpq that I placed in my client WotLK/Data/ directory, and then on the server, I placed the DBC file into the worldserver/data/dbc/ directory, replacing the original DBC.

I think this can optionally be overwritten in the database, by using the associated _dbc table to override values from the dbc files (someone correct me if this part is wrong).